# pip install fails "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install some packages using pip, but keep getting the error bellow.

```
 pip3 install flask
Collecting flask
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/flask/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask
```

I've tried to install several packages (numpy, scipy and matplotlib), all of them failed with a similar error message.

I've tried to use include `--trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org` in the command (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768) answer) and using easy_install, none of it worked.

It's not an issue with my firewall, as it still doesn't work after having turned it off.

P.S.: I'm using a virtual environment, but, that does not seem to influence the outcome. And, when I try to access [pypi](https://pypi.org/), through the browser, most of the time it says that the website can't be reached.

Comment: "And, when I try to access pypi, through the browser, most of the time it says that the website can't be reached." This is unrelated to pip. That's the actual problem. Get that taken care of and then this should be fixed too.

Comment: Do you any idea on how I could get that taken care of?